# OpenACC; copy_in not working?

Tags: gpu, directive, pragma, openacc, accelerator

I have this sample code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #ifdef _OPENACC
 #include <openacc.h>
 #endif

 #define N 1000

 int main() {

    #ifdef _OPENACC
    acc_init(acc_device_not_host);
    printf(" Compiling with OpenACC support \n");
    #endif 


   double * a;
   int n = 100;
   a = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   a[i] = 1.0f;
   #pragma acc data copy_in(a[0:n])
   {
    #pragma acc kernels loop
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = (double) i + a[i];
   }

  #ifdef _OPENACC
   acc_shutdown(acc_device_not_host);
  #endif 



  printf("Value of a[10]: %lf\n", a[10]);

  return 0;
```

}

Teacher told me that the output is 1.0, because I have copy_in; then, a is copied on the acceñeratpr, but when it ends, a contains 1.0 in every position; but if I run this code I get 11.0, why?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things going on here. First, the correct clause is `copyin` (no underscore). Second, since you're only copying the input values into the region, any changes made within the data region will not come back to the CPU, so unless you're running this on a shared memory system, for example running on a multicore CPU, then the value of `a` at your `printf` statement will be like that loop never ran. In order to get the results back from the data region, you'll actually want a `copy` clause instead. That informs the compiler to copy in the input values to the region and copy out the output values from the region.

Since you're getting 11, clearly the loop is getting run somewhere. What compiler are you using and what flags? Either you're not actually building with OpenACC enabled or you're running on a shared memory target and your teacher isn't.